# Undoing a git bisect mistake

Tags: git, git-bisect

I'm doing a non-automated git bisect via command line. All is going well until I accidentally hit return on the wrong line in my command history, and rather than running the test, I run 'git bisect good' (or bad). Oops - I don't yet know if this commit should be marked good or bad, yet that's what I've done.

Can I undo the 'git bisect good' command, or make git forget the result of it, and go back and run the test for that commit?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

From the [git-bisect documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_log_and_bisect_replay):

> **Bisect log and bisect replay**
>
> After having marked revisions as good or bad, issue the following command to show what has been done so far:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect log
> ```
>
> If you discover that you made a mistake in specifying the status of a revision, you can save the output of this command to a file, edit it to remove the incorrect entries, and then issue the following commands to return to a corrected state:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect reset
> $ git bisect replay that-file
> ```

Comment: Too complicated, too many it-dependses. What command or sequence of commands, taking NO parameters depending on the current repository state (i.e. "that-file"), will GUARANTEEDLY reset the repository to the state just before the erroneous command?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski This literally took 25 seconds from I read it to me being exactly where I was before I mistakenly issued a `git bisect good` too many. There are no "it depends" bits here. Just literally do it. It is not complicated. `git bisect log > f; vim f; git bisect reset; git bisect replay f;`

Comment: And them `rm f` (or `rm that-file`) :) I know it's obvious, but it triggers me when I see instructions that leave unused files on your system (I know that in this case, being about a git repository, you'll notice it, but it's not always the case).

Comment: @oligofren I think the first comment was looking for something like `git bisect undo`, which would be pretty nice...

Comment: Well, he could add an alias for that in his `.gitconfig`: `bisect-undo = 'git bisect log | sed -e '$ d' > /tmp/trimmed-log; git bisect reset; git bisect replay /tmp/trimmed-log; rm /tmp/trimmed-log;`. Then he could do `git bisect-undo` all he wants :)

Answer (score 133):

You can output a record of what was done using

```
$ git bisect log > bisect.log
```

Open that file in an editor and edit/remove the faulty line. Then you can replay it with

```
$ git bisect replay bisect.log
```

This is documented in [`git help bisect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-bisect).

Comment: Do you have to also `git bisect reset` as @manojlds answer indicated?

Comment: @ColinD I did not have to reset first. I'm using git version 2.19.1.windows.1

Comment: I had to reset first, using git version 2.25.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to undo your last instruction in one go, without having to use a text editor, you can use the following command:

```
git bisect log | head -n -2 > /tmp/fixed_bisect.log ; git bisect replay /tmp/fixed_bisect.log
```

It will remove the two last lines of the log (because there's a comment + the actual command it corresponds to), then save that to file and directly reuse it with `bisect replay`. (Unfortunately, `bisect replay` can't receive input directly with the pipe, so it needs to create a temporary intermediate file.)

To make it even easier, you can add an alias to your .bashrc or equivalent:

```bash
# bisect undo alias
alias bisectundo="git bisect log | head -n -2 > /tmp/fixed_bisect.log ; git bisect replay /tmp/fixed_bisect.log"
```

In a new session, you will be able to simply use `bisectundo` to go one step back.

---

If you get an "illegal line count" error for the negative number argument (which is because [some implementations of `head` don't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336903/1494531)), you can use this longer form, which bases the number of lines to keep on the length of the log using `wc`:

```bash
git bisect log | head -n $(($(git bisect log | wc -l)-2)) > /tmp/fixed_bisect.log ; git bisect replay /tmp/fixed_bisect.log
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but your suggestion gives a `head: illegal line count -- -2`

Comment: @henrique I adapted my answer with an option for when that happens.