# Negative arguments to head

Tags: linux, macos, zsh, tail, head

I was trying using `head` command, in macOS using zsh, code below,

```
a.txt:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

tail -n +5 a.txt   // line 5 to line end

tail -n -5 a.txt   // last line 5 to line end

head -n +5 a.txt // line 1 to line 5

head -n -5 a.txt  // # What did this do?
```

The last command shows an error.

```
head: illegal line count -- -5
```

What did head -n -5 actually do?

Comment: `man head` should answer all your questions.

Comment: Shows *what* error? And have you tried to read [the `head` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hi , i add the error

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336903/1207193

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it doesn't, because `man head` on a Mac does not show any information at all, and although `info head` does, it still shows valid negative `-n` flag, which isn't supported by the macOs. So the question is valid and the answer is not in the manual :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some implementations* of `head` like GNU `head` support negative arguments for `-n`

**But that's not standard!** Your case is clearly not **supported.**

**When supported** The negative argument should remove the last `5 lines` before doing the `head`

Answer (score 0):

It becomes more clear, if using `3` instead of `5`. Note the signs!

```
# print 10 lines:
seq 10

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

#-------------------------    
# get the last 3 lines:
seq 10 | tail -n 3

8
9
10

#--------------------------------------
# start at line 3 (skip first 2 lines)
seq 10 | tail -n +3

3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

#-------------------------    
# get the first 3 lines:
seq 10 | head -n 3

1
2
3

#-------------------------    
# skip the last 3 lines:
seq 10 | head -n -3

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

btw, `man tail` and `man head` explain this behavior.