# Cannot replay git bisect: "error: couldn't get the oid of the rev"

Tags: git, powershell, newline, git-bisect

I am attempting to replay a `git bisect` from an edited log to [undo a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594758/undoing-a-git-bisect-mistake) I made.

I mistakenly marked one of the commits as good when it should have been bad (or vice versa). I ran:

```bsh
git bisect log > C:\temp\bisect.log
# Alternatively
git bisect log | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII C:\temp\bisect.log
```

Then I edited that file to remove all the lines from the mistakenly labeled commit and below.

I then ran:

```bsh
git bisect reset
git bisect replay c:\temp\bisect.log
```

I'm now getting the error:

> ```
> We are not bisecting.
> Bisecting: 5211 revisions left to test after this (roughly 12 steps)
> [9bc79b2f25a3724376d7af19617c33749a30ea3a] Merge branch 'release/2.1' into release/2.2
> error: couldn't get the oid of the rev '9bc79b2f25a3724376d7af19617c33749a30ea3a?'
> ```

What is going on? How do I fix it? (Why is there a '?' at the end of the revision?)

I'm using git version 2.26.2.windows.1 on Windows 10. I use PowerShell 7 as my shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git bisect replay` in Git before version 2.27 is unable to handle CRLF delimited files. The best fix for this is to upgrade to Git 2.27+, which has [a contribution of mine to fix this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.27.0.txt).

PowerShell's massaging of the output of `git bisect log` converted the originally LF-only output of `git bisect log` to CRLF. You can see where the errant CR is showing up: it's the '?' in the error message.

If you cannot upgrade your copy of Git, there are a number of ways to avoid this:

- Convert the file from CRLF back to LF.

  - If you're using PowerShell 5+, `` ((Get-Content C:\temp\bisect.log ) -join "`n") + "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline \temp\bisect-lf.log ``
- Have your text editor save the file with LF during editing.
- Use CMD instead of PowerShell. Then, `git bisect log > c:\temp\bisect.log` won't change the newlines.

Hat tip to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127741/replace-crlf-using-powershell/48919146#48919146) for the PowerShell conversion one-liner. See it for nitty-gritty details.

There's a [proposal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3855) to add a `-Delimiter` argument to `Set-Content`. If that get implemented, such conversion will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Warrington's ([`chwarr`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392683/chwarr), the OP) patch has been merged in Git 2.27 (Q2 2020): "[`git bisect replay`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)" had trouble with input files when they used CRLF line ending, which has been corrected.

See [commit 6c722cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c722cbe5a919166eb0d7369762b09393eb5b518) (07 May 2020) by [Christopher Warrington (`chwarr`)](https://github.com/chwarr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f9dbe28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9dbe28d62f9d7f110149ba78f4af7ef50ab1181), 14 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c722cbe5a919166eb0d7369762b09393eb5b518): allow CRLF line endings in "git bisect replay" input
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christopher Warrington</sup>
>
> We advertise that the bisect log can be corrected in your editor before being fed to "[`git bisect replay`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)", but some editors may turn the line endings to CRLF.
>
> Update the parser of the input lines so that the CR at the end of the line gets ignored.
>
> Were anyone to intentionally be using terms/revs with embedded CRs, replaying such bisects will no longer work with this change. I suspect that this is incredibly rare.